# How do I access my SHiFT code golden keys in the Pre-Sequel?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've been dutifully entering Shift codes since the Pre-Sequel launched, and I should have over 20 saved up by now.

When I finally got around to visiting the golden key chest, I saw that I had only 9 keys. I redeemed a new code from today that should have added one key, but upon visiting the chest again I still had only 9. When I opened the chest, my count went down to 8 as expected.

Is there a cap on golden keys? Or is something else going on here?

Comment: Norepro. I had 10 until I spent 2

Comment: I've had over 30 until spending some

Comment: Handy tip when entering codes into Shift.  If you remove the - marks from a code, so that you just have a string of letters and numbers, you can copy (ctrl-c) and paste (ctrl-v) the code directly into the shift code field.

Comment: @MadMAxJr I've been pasting them in with the hyphens included, and that seems to work. Has it not worked for you?

Comment: @FeralChimp It will fill in the first block for me, but not the rest if the hyphens are in.  Whatever works I suppose.

Comment: @MadMAxJr Weird. Yesterday I pasted in a Shift code including the dashes. There must be some difference between your and my setup, but I can't imagine what. Regardless, I guess it's worth people trying the easy way (with dashes) in case it works for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to visit the Shift station (across the square from the Fast Travel station in Concordia) in order to claim your golden keys. Golden keys are still stored in your global profile, so keys redeemed on one character are available to all of your characters.

Comment: Based on my first few minutes playing a new character, they don't seem to be character tied; I had 22 keys immediately when starting.

Comment: @Unionhawk: Okay, then the interface just implies that.  It's odd that you can enter the shift code from the main menu, but you have to claim them with a character.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. It seems pointless to have to redeem it after entering a code. (you should be able to enter shift codes in Concordia in-game too, not just from the main menu)

Comment: I know (which is nice), but you can't claim the keys from the main menu.  Maybe it's going to be used more for customizations from shift codes, but those were for all characters, too, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks much MBraedley. I'd visited the SHiFT console a couple of times but only saw the social media promotional info; didn't notice the golden key management button. @Unionhawk, it is possible to enter SHiFT codes in-game -- I've updated my question with complete instructions.

Comment: Keys are not tied to individual characters.  The number unused is still stored in your profile.bin file.  Creating a new character will quickly verify this, as will saving a copy of your profile.bin file, spending all your keys, exiting game, and restoring the old profile.bin

Answer (score 7):

In the Pre-Sequel, Shift key redemption has become a multi-step process.

I'm expanding on the accepted answer and other comments with a complete walk-through.

1. **Enter a Shift code.** Orcz maintains [a good list](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_Pre-Sequel:_Shift_Codes). You can do this in the game's main menu at Extras > Shift Code (menu option) > Shift Code (button). You can also do it in-game as described below.
2. **Get to the "town square" in Concordia.** If you begin at the fast travel console in town square, you can use the jump pad directly in front of you to reach the next location: the Shift kiosk. [image]
3. **Visit and activate the Shift kiosk in town square.** This will show you a screen that (currently) just promotes Borderlands social media sites. But if you look up, you'll see a tab-button with a key and a gear as shown below. Click it. [image]
4. **Enter keys in-game if you wish.** Now you're on the golden key management screen. If you haven't entered Shift codes on the game's main menu, you can enter them here. [image]
5. **Activate the redeemed keys.** You should see one or more keys on the left; the screenshot above shows one. Click a key to *truly* activate it.

And now (finally) you can spend your golden keys at the mysterious chest in town square. I imagine Gearbox made the process more cumbersome for a reason, but it's not apparent to me.