# Is there a level requirement to see the shift kiosk?

Tags: macos, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I am playing Borderlands and I'm in Concodria looking at town square, and there is no shift kiosk for me. Is it because I am only level 7, or because I am on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a level requirement; I've reached Concordia pretty early and still seen the kiosk.

Make sure you're looking in the right place. [This question is related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188688/how-do-i-access-my-shift-code-golden-keys-in-the-pre-sequel/189093#189093), and the answer I posted there includes a screenshot showing the kiosk's location.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get your game from the Mac App Store? I know that version doesn't work with Shift, so maybe the kiosk doesn't even appear. The Mac version on Steam however, does work with Shift